# Selecting rows based on previous period - retained users

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to determine a list of users who have been active in period1 and also active in period2 - essentially a way to calculate retaining users.
This is the data I have

[image]

And I would like to get only the users / or have an indicator for each row if the user also shows up in the previous period. A period in this case is 3 days.
Utlimately, I would like to determine if a user has an entry (for any row) is there another entry 3 days prior to that. I have tried a self join, but this only seems to work on exact dates, and not when there is an inconsistent time pattern.

Basically, a lookback window of 3 calendar days that determines if there is an entry, yes or no.

What is the best way to solve this, is a self join with a time frame an option?

Thank you.

```
WITH data1 as (
  SELECT DATE("2021-01-02") date, 'abc' user UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE("2021-01-03") date, 'abc' user UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE("2021-01-04") date, 'abc' user UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE("2021-01-09") date, 'abc' user UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE("2021-01-10") date, 'abc' user UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE("2021-01-11") date, 'abc' user UNION ALL   
  SELECT DATE("2021-01-04") date, 'aaa' user UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE("2021-01-09") date, 'aaa' user UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE("2021-01-10") date, 'aaa' user 
)

SELECT  
  data1.*
FROM data1 as data1
JOIN data1 as data_forward
  ON data1.user = data_forward.user
  AND data1.date = DATE_ADD(data_forward.date, INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

Comment: Please provide sample results.  How are the three days measured?  From the first time a user appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
select date, user, 
  count(1) over period2 > 0 is_in_period2
from data1
window period2 as (
  partition by user 
  order by unix_date(date)
  range between 3 preceding and 1 preceding
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note: period2 in above  - is considered three previous days  - you can control this in respective expression below

```
range between 3 preceding and 1 preceding
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a lookback of 3 days *on each row*, then I think the simplest method is just `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       ( lag(date) over (partition by user order by date) >= date_add(date, interval -3 day)
       ) as is_in_previous_period
from t;
```

`lag()` looks at the immediately preceding row for the user.  If the date on that row is within 3 days, then the flag is `TRUE`.